# What are some free kid-friendly tutorials to get started with Mindstorms Nxt 2.0?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

My daughter (10) got the NXT 2.0 for christmas. It doesn't really come with any tutorial. I'm looking for something she can follow which will teach her to use each of the sensors and slightly more advanced topics like executing a 90 degree turn (how to find exactly the # of rotations of each wheel to do that for your particular turning radius).

Can be any free resource (YouTube videos, etc.)

Comment: 90 Degrees = 0.25 Rotations. Using the drop-down box you can choose between Unlimited, Degrees, Rotations and Seconds.

Comment: Doesn't it come with an "online" tutorial on the disc that takes you through various topics?

Comment: @Zhaph, no it does not come with a tutorial.

Comment: @Ambo100  : rotations refers to TIRE rotations. But if I want to turn the *vehicle* I have to rotate one of the wheels (left or right) more than the other one to make the vehicle turn. And how *much* more depends on the turning radius of the vehicle. (I made the same mistake originally.).

Comment: @ClayNichols: Ah. NXT-G supports that. You can use the Move block (not to be confused with the Motor block)

Comment: @Ambo100 - The Move block has a setting (with no actual value, just a slider range) for how sharply you want to turn, but you then tell it how far to move through that turn in WHEEL rotations. So you can't just say "turn 90 degrees to the right". If you think about it, that makes sense b/c the "brain" doesn't know how wide the axle is, so it doesn't know how many rotations of a single wheel to make in order to make a 90d right turn.

Comment: Unless you're using a compass sensor, they easiest way to figure out how to make a 90° turn is by trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find some free instructions at http://www.nxtprograms.com/ and at http://thenxtstep.blogspot.com/p/building-instructions.html. But I am not sure if you can say they are kid-friendly.

And here is another one:  http://legoengineering.com/curriculum-submenuteachingresources-142.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the most heavily used is mine at [NXT Tutorial](http://www.ortop.org/NXT_Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for posting that Dale. Would it be possible for you to add a little more context to this answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [NXT User Guide](http://cache.lego.com/r/education/-/media/lego%20education/home/downloads/user%20guides/global/mindstorms/ts.20101019t110252.9797_lme_userguide_us_low.pdf) available from LEGO education, but it deosn't seem to conatin much in the way of tutorials.

While these are not free resources, you (or other people asking themselves that kind of question) could also have a look at [various printed books](http://thenxtstep.blogspot.be/p/books.html) on the subject.

In particular, "[LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT: The Mayan Adventure (Technology in Action)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159059763X)" is very accessible, and you can see a few sample chapters in the first link. There is a [forum](http://thenxtstep.com/smf/index.php?board=10.0) devoted to it, apparently. Interestingly, LEGO education sells a [parts pack](http://www.legoeducation.us/eng/product/mayan_adventure_parts_pack/1441) for it, which should say something about the quality fo the book.